# Basic Maven iText program in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, nullpointerexception, itext7

I need to generate a Pdf document from some data that is located in a database and I came across iTEXT 7. I just started my first Maven project on Netbeans (started with a basic hello world) and this is the output:

> Building mavenproject2 1.0-SNAPSHOT
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>            at com.mycompany.mavenproject2.class2.main(class2.java:18)
>       BUILD FAILURE
>       [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>     Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>       [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

CODE :

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject2;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import java.io.*;

public class class2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        File file = new File("hello.pdf");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("hello.pdf");
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdf);
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
        document.close();
    }
}
```

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>itext</id>
            <name>iText Repository - releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- add all iText Core modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- pdfSweep -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cleanup</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- pdfCalligraph -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>typography</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- pdfInvoice -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>zugferd</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- pdfHTML -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- pdfXFA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfxfa</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- iText 7 License Key Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-licensekey</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: With that short piece of code, you don't need all of the iText add-ons. You only use kernel and layout so that is all you need in your POM. Because they are on Maven Central, you don't need to add the iText repo either.

Comment: If you have purchased a license, then you also need the license key library, and then you still need the iText repository.

Comment: Delete the cleanup, typography, zugferd, html2pdf, pdfxfa dependencies. Replace core with kernel and layout. And use version 7.0.4 which was released 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Thank you @AmedeeVanGasse for your help. I got rid of all the extra dependencies and put in kernel, io and layout. I wasn't aware that I needed to purchase a license, I just included the repository that was mentioned on the iText website. I just applied for an AGPL License. Hope that comes along.

Comment: You only need to purchase a license when you distribute your software as closed source (commercial). If you do not distribute your software, or if you distribute it as open source with the AGPL license, then you do not need to buy a license. You don't need to apply for an AGPL license, it is the default.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Oh I see. Could you please post the repository that I need to add for the license. I can&#39;t seem to find it. 
Thank you .

Comment: No, I can't right now. I left the office for a long weekend and I am on my phone now.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse that's fine. You can post it when you're back.

Comment: Hi Suzume. I notice that your questions are a bit chatty, and I wonder if you would be able to post them in more succinctly? In particular, they tend to end with "Please help me [out]", which to native English speakers may be understood as a form of pleading. Thanks if you can leave this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the POM file I use for simple projects:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>itext-releases</id>
        <name>iText Repository - releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>     

...

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext-licensekey</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    ...

</dependencies>
```

As suggested in the comments, it includes the releases (needed for license-key) and the dependency to the license-key repository.